# Spring MVC Ajax Post @ModelAttribute (Send object json to method controller)

Tags: json, ajax, spring, post, model-view-controller

i have a problem with sending JSON object to method controller from javascript. Below is a snippet code of javascript:

```
$.getJSON("/api/tasks/" + id)
.done(function( task ) {
  $.post("/tasks/update", {
      id: task.id,
      version: task.version,
      name: task.name,
      description: task.description,
      priority: task.priority,
      finished: task.finished,
      category: task.category
    });
});
```

And method controller which should receive json object

```
@PostMapping(path = "update")
public String processUpdateForm(@ModelAttribute @Valid Task task, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
      return TASK_EDIT_FORM;
    }

    taskService.updateTask(task);

    return redirectTo("/tasks");
```

}

The problem begins if i want to send the last property category: task.category which is nested object, i got following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'category[id]' of bean class [pl.java.learning.todolist.domain.task.Task]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'category[id]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [Category(name=null)]
```

I noticed the method can't handle category[id] which i suppose should be category.id ?
I spent on this problem a with days with a lot of combination(ex. RequestBody, different structure JSON(JSON.parse or JSON.stringify)) but with no good results.
Maybe someone had this or similiar problem and can give me a tips what should i do?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer on my problem, maybe in future someone will have the similiar so i leave solution below:

Javascript snippet code:

```
$.getJSON("/api/tasks/" + id)
.done(function(task) {
  $.ajax("/api/tasks", {
    data: JSON.stringify(task),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST'
  });
});
```

Method controller snippet code:

```
@PostMapping
  public void addTask(@RequestBody Task task) {
    taskService.addTask(task);
  }
```

I don't know if it is one of the good solution, but for my purposes is enough for now.

Regards